# IntegrationComponentScan with an explicit basePackages required in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, spring-integration, spring-annotations, component-scan

I have a Spring Boot application (using **Spring Boot 2.4.11**) where I'm using Spring Integration. I added the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration` and hence I expected `@IntegrationComponentScan` to be active by default. Indeed, I find [Issue 2037](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2037) that seems to suggest this. Also, I see that annotation on `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfigurationScanRegistrar.IntegrationComponentScanConfiguration`.

However, my `@MessagingGateway` annotated interfaces were not taken up by Spring. I tried to add an explicit `@IntegrationComponentScan` on one of my `@Configuration` classes, but it didn't work either.

It started to work once I also specified an explicit `basePackages` value for that annotation, so:

```java
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.app.integration")
public class MyConfigurationClass {
}
```

and of course my annotated interfaces are in a package below `com.example.app.integration`.

Am I missing something? I couldn't find any reference to `@IntegrationComponentScan` in Spring Boot documentation. Other similar annotations (like `@EnableJpaRepositories` for Spring Data or `@EntityScan`) are not strictly necessary, unless you need to customize the scanning scope.

I also found [Issue 3375](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3375), that seems to suggest that I should look at `@AutoConfigurationPackage`, but:

- I can't find any mention to this annotation in Spring Boot documentation
- I suspect this will apply to ANY other "scan" annotation enabled by Spring Boot, so my `basePackages` in this case must probably point to some package very close to the "root" of my application
- why isn't this annotation required by other `@*Scan` annotations like the above ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to show your project structure. It works as expected:

1. I have an interface like `com.example.integration.gateway.MyGateway`
2. My main class is in the `com.example.integration.IntegrationApplication` with a content like:

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class IntegrationApplication {
   ```

It still works even if I have that `MyGateway` in the `com.example.integration` package.

To conclude. The `@SpringBootApplication` is marked with the `@ComponentScan` where Spring starts scanning components from the package where this `@SpringBootApplication` is declared and all the way down to its sub-packages.

If your components are in a different from `@SpringBootApplication` class, then consider to have it customized via its `scanBasePackages` property:

```
/**
 * Base packages to scan for annotated components. Use {@link #scanBasePackageClasses}
 * for a type-safe alternative to String-based package names.
 * <p>
 * <strong>Note:</strong> this setting is an alias for
 * {@link ComponentScan @ComponentScan} only. It has no effect on {@code @Entity}
 * scanning or Spring Data {@link Repository} scanning. For those you should add
 * {@link org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan @EntityScan} and
 * {@code @Enable...Repositories} annotations.
 * @return base packages to scan
 * @since 1.3.0
 */
@AliasFor(annotation = ComponentScan.class, attribute = "basePackages")
String[] scanBasePackages() default {};
```

Everything else needs an investigation already inside your project. If you can share that with us, we can take a look and find something.

**UPDATE**

Turned out when an XML configuration for `<int:gateway>` is in use, Spring Boot auto-configuration for `@IntegrationComponentScan` backs-off and requires to be provided explicitly to make `@MessagingGateway` interfaces to be visible. This problem was fixed in Spring Boot `3.0` as a side-effect of [some other fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/95557ddbc6a8cae55aba85ca7d5d21078a3bc105).

Comment: Hi Artem, I discovered what is causing this, although I don't have a reproducing example. Spring Boot 2.7.10 with spring-integration starter: my `@MessagingGateway` annotated bean is autodetected without the need to add anything else. Then, add a XML configuration file (using `@ImportResource`) and in this XML declare an `<int:gateway>`: bam! The `@MessagingGateway` bean is not detected any more, unless I add an explicit `@IntegrationComponentScan`!

Comment: By playing with the devtools I found out that it seems like the problem is this: `IntegrationAutoConfiguration.IntegrationComponentScanConfiguration: Did not match:
- @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean' &myGateway (OnBeanCondition)`.
In other words: by declaring that `<int:gateway>`, the `IntegrationComponentScanConfiguration` gets disabled. Why can't both techniques (gateways in XML and annotated gateways) live together?

Comment: Was fixed in Spring Boot `3.0`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/95557ddbc6a8cae55aba85ca7d5d21078a3bc105

Comment: Thank you Artem! If you promote your last comment as an answer or change the above one, I will mark it as the accepted answer! 

Comment: Sure! Added an UPDATE into my answer.